# Different results updating a variable out/in-side constructor

Tags: c#, timer, anonymous-function

B's width isn't reduced

```
class A
{
    //..
        B b = new B();  
}

class B
{
    //...
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(10);
            t.Start();
            t.Elapsed += (_,__) =>
            {
                width -= 5
            };
}
```

B's width is reduced

```
class A
{
    //...
    B b = new B();  
}

class B
{
    //...
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(10);
            t.Start();
            t.Elapsed += (_,__) =>
            {
                update();
            };

    private void update()
    {
        width -= 5;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain how these two differ enough to yield such different results?
Maybe I just don't understand how anonymous functions work..

Comment: where is width declared? how has you width declared?

Comment: Where is constructor code?